# Using jQuery UI icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery UI comes with handy icons in a sprite image; see the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

I have an `input` element for which I want the clock icon (with class `.ui-icon-clock`) as background image. How do I have a background icon to an `input`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

just use an empty span and add the jQuery UI classes.

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-clock" style="display:inline-block"></span><input type="text" />
```

You have to override the display style to make it inline-block rather than block otherwise the input will be pushed to the next line.

Other than that, I'm not sure exactly what you're after when you say make the clock the background image.

Comment: Is this really the right answer?  I thought explicitly defining styles in html was strongly discouraged as merging the "content" and "display" concerns.

Comment: You're right, but CSS best practices are an exercise for the reader. The answer identifies what it takes to display a jQuery icon. The `ui-icon` and `ui-icon-clock` classes and making your html element take up space.

Comment: -1 Best practices are for everybody. No reason not to put the best possible answer here.

Comment: @mehasse Perhaps a comment or side-note is in order here, but adding an additional class name and attached css will make this answer overly verbose IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with JQuery UI script.

JS:

```
$(function() {
   $("input").button({
     icons: {
       primary: ".ui-icon-clock"
     },
     text: false
   })
});
```

HTML:

```
<input>some text</input>
```

See http://jqueryui.com/button/#icons

Answer (score 4):

```
$( "span").css({ 
width: 16px; 
height: 16px; 
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); // change to correct location
background-position: -80px -112px; 
});
```

Comment: you should donwload a jqueryui theme from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
Click on the Gallery tab at the ThemeRoller and choose the one you like