# How to add an icon in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, icons

In jquery mobile, I dynamically add a tag like this:

```
str += '<img class="ui-icon-location"/>' + obj['address'] + ', ' + obj['city'] + ', ' + obj['country'];
```

I want to put the location icon to the left of the text. The icon itself comes from the class. But since the src isn't there, I don't actually see the icon. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<div>` tag instead on `<img>` tag. You need to add one more class `ui-icon`

```
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-location"></div>
```

Note: Apply the same css for `<div>` tag.

update: in case you want to use span

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-location" style="display: inline-block"/>
```

Comment: My bad, I got confused with glyphicons...the jQuery mobile icons can be applied to buttons, div and spans etc

Comment: The icon doesn't show up because there is no content in the div. I don't think fixing a size is a good idea too because then it doesn't scale well on different device sizes.

Comment: [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290857/using-jquery-ui-icons) says to use `span` not `div`

Comment: I tried `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-location" style="display:inline-block"></span>`, but again no icon shows because there is no content and it ends up being 0px by 0px...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
<span class="ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-left" style="position:relative;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For an inline icon, you can use a span and some CSS

```
<span class="ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></span>

.inlineIcon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

So for your dynamic insert:

```
var str = '<span class="ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"/>' + obj["address"] + ', ' + obj["city"] + ', ' + obj["country"];    
$("#dynamicText").empty().append(str);
```

If you prefer a black icon without the gray disk in the background:

```
<span class="ui-alt-icon ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIconNoDisk"></span>

.inlineIconNoDisk {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.inlineIconNoDisk:after {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

> Here is a demo with both options: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5v4ycz6y/1/)**